# How do I make the timer/clock move by the seconds?

Tags: python, pyqt5

this is my code, when i run it, it doesnt act like a clock. all it does it return a string. but what i wanted was the time moving by the seconds. help will be appreciated thank you

```
def DateTime(self):
    dateandtime = QDialog()

    dateandtime.setWindowTitle("Date and Time")

    hbox = QHBoxLayout()

    datetime = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
    show = datetime.toString(Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate)

    label = QLabel(show)
    label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 10))
    hbox.addWidget(label)

    dateandtime.setLayout(hbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a more elegant way, but find an example with a timer:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDateTime, Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        datetime = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        show = datetime.toString(Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate)
        self.label = QLabel(show)
        self.DateTime()

    def DateTime(self):
        # dateandtime = QDialog()
        self.setWindowTitle("Date and Time")
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 10))
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

    def tick(self):
        datetime = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString(Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate)
        self.label.setText(datetime)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = Dialog()
dialog.show()
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(dialog.tick)
timer.start(1000)
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Will try the code out.